# What is the best way to include eps files in large documents?

Tags: graphics, eps

I am updating an old LaTeX file from the university where I work, which over the past ten years has been partly edited and contributed to by several people, using different methods to include eps files.

Some eps files are included using:

```
\epsfxsize=8cm
\epsfbox{../kap_5/bilder/ekvabsolut.eps}
```

and others using

```
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{../kap3/bilder/analytiskFig1.eps}
```

What are the differences between the two methods? Which is the recommended method to include eps files in a document compiled with pdflatex, and why?

Comment: The »[graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)« package with its `\includegraphics` command is definitely the way to go (not only for EPS files).

Comment: Do  you need to put annotations on some of the EPS files? If yes then you cannot simply use `\includegraphics` but you need one more thing to do.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: why?

Comment: Because »[epsfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/epsfig)« is obsolete for a long time and only a wrapper for »[graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)«. Furthermore the latter one also includes other graphics formats like JPG, PNG or PDF (depending on the used compiler).

Comment: @TheLastError -- please don't leave us in the dark.  what is the "one more thing" you say needs to be done if `\epsfbox` is replaced by `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: No more thing to do only for such a replacement. But if other files to be included must be annotated as well, then the story becomes different. That was what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx%20graphicx) package is by far the most used package for including graphics. You might want to convert the eps files to pdf using something like [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/%20ghostscript) or Acrobat Destiller (last I checked eps and pdflatex was not good friends).

Although if you need to include a full pdf-page in latex the package [pdfpages](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf%20pdfpages) is what you need.

Comment: Conversion from EPS to PDF is done "on the fly" in TeX Live out of the box and in MiKTeX by the »[epstopdf](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg)« package.

Answer (score 1):

In recent TeX distributions (starting from TeX Live 2011 if I remember correctly concerning TeX Live), the `graphicx` package has also the advantage of automatically converting your eps files in pdf files when needed, e.g. when you are using PDFLaTeX. The other method can't.